# invalidateLater issue

Tags: r, shiny

in a shiny app I got built in an invalidation condition for time cycle of one day (86400000 millisecs = 24 hours). Worked fine till a system restart and instalation of new R version 3.2.4. Now it doesn`t work properly. What i mean is the invalidation intervals do not match and after some time the process seems to expire.

I tried to test it with 30 sec interval:

```
invalidateLater(30000, session)
```

Using a `cat` function I can track when was the refresh of the reactive object innitiated:

```
MyData <- reactive({   # Responds to changes. But in here, only the invalidation triggers change.
invalidateLater(30000, session) # Invalidates MyData() after 30000 millisecs = 30 secs.
connection <- odbcConnect(dns, usr, pass)
SituationToday<-{cat(Sys.time());sqlQuery(connection, "SELECT ALL * FROM Table;")}
odbcClose(connection)
SituationToday
})
```

The triggers outcome from the cat function is in UNIX format:

```
val<-c(1458036067,1458036158,1458036251,1458036340,1458036430,1458036519,1458036608,1458036700)
```

The time differences between the individual time points are not what I expected:

```
diff(as.POSIXct(val, origin="1970-01-01"))
```

Time differences in mins:

```
[1] 1.516667 1.550000 1.483333 1.500000 1.483333 1.483333 1.533333
```

That´s far from 30 sec interval as desired. Moreover, that´s all I get, the invalidation process stops after 11 mins aproximately (UNIX time value 458036700).

I use shiny v. 0.13.1,
shinydashbaord 0.5.1,
R 3.2.4, Windows Server2012R2.

Anyone has an idea what can be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: How long does your query take to execute?

Comment: i used a simplified version to run, not 30 secs.